# Uninstall Jupyter-Lab with conda completely

Tags: python, installation, conda, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to reinstall Jupyter-Lab with conda completely. I mean, when I run `uninstall jupyterlab` and install it again, the system already comes with configuration I had previously, such as extensions installed. Therefore, there is something that is still present after the uninstall.

Hence, how do I completely remove jupyter-lab and install it again from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jupyterlab is installed use `jupyter --paths` to see where the configuration, data and runtime is stored. After removing the corresponding files and directories you will be able to perform a clean install without any traces of the old extensions.

Remember to use it in the right environment.